# Compare and join two columns in two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two data frames with the same column types.

**First Dataframe (df1)**

```
data = [['BTC', 2], ['ETH', 1], ['ADA', 100]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Coin', 'Quantity'])
```

```
Coin     Quantity
BTC          2
ETH          1
ADA        100
...        ...
```

**Second Dataframe (df2)**

```
data = [['BTC', 50000], ['FTM', 50], ['ETH', 1500], ['LRC', 5], ['ADA', 20]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['code_name', 'selling rate'])
```

```
code_name     selling rate
BTC               50000
FTM                  50
ETH                1500
LRC                   5
ADA                  20
...                 ...
```

**Expected output (FTM and LRC should be removed)**

```
Coin     Quantity     selling rate
BTC          2           50000
ETH          1            1500
ADA        100              20
...        ...             ...
```

**What I have tried**

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['Coin'], right_on=['code_name'])
```

```
df = np.where(df1['Coin'] == df2['code_name'])
```

Both codes did not give me the expected output. I searched on StackOverflow and couldn't find any helpful answer. Can anyone give a solution or make this question as duplicate if a related question exist?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in your example, but `code_name` in your "What I have tried" section is lower case, but `Code_name` in your description of `df2` is not entirely lower case.

Comment: Sorry, `code_name` is in simple letters. I have edited it

Comment: Just to be clear, does your expected output have rows from `df2` that do not appear in `df1`? In other words, should `LRC` and `FTM` both be included in your expected output?

Comment: No, I want remove non-equal rows from final outcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is an inner join, not an outer join. Inner joins only retain records that are common in the two tables you're joining together.

```
import pandas as pd

# Make the first data frame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Coin': ['BTC', 'ETH', 'ADA'],
    'Quantity': [2, 1, 100]
})

# Make the second data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'code_name': ['BTC', 'FTM', 'ETH', 'LRC', 'ADA'],
    'selling_rate': [50000, 50, 1500, 5, 20]
})

# Merge the data frames via inner join. This only keeps entries that appear in
# both data frames
full_df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', left_on = 'Coin', right_on = 'code_name')

# Drop the duplicate column
full_df = full_df.drop('code_name', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `merge()` is slow for large dataset. I prefer not to use it as long as I have a faster solution. Therefore, I suggest the following:

```
full_df = df1.copy()
full_df['selling_rate'] = list(
    df2['selling_rate'][df2['code_name'].isin(df1['Coin'].unique())])
```

**Note:** This turns to the expected solution if `df1` and `df2` are in the same order with respect to `Coin` and `code_name`. If they are not, you should use `sort_values()` before the above code.

Comment: Good suggestions. I didn't consider `sort_values()` before. +1